# Finding maximum subset of given set of inequalities which has a solution

Tags: c#

I'm new here and this is my first question. So, directly on the topic.
I have a task that i can't solve and i will be happy if someone can provide me with directions to the solution. The main problem is that i can't understand completely what should be my final output.

This is the task:

You are given a set of inequalities. Each of the inequalities refers to the variable X. Determine the maximum subset of the given set which has a solution. 
The input file inequalities.in will contain a list of at most 50 inequalities, one inequality per line. Each inequality is given in one of the following forms: “X < C”, “X <= C”, “X = C”, “X > C” or “X >= C” where C is some integer constant (possibly different for different inequalities). The input data will be correct and it is not required to check it explicitly.
On the first line of the output file inequalities.out print the integer K: the maximum number of inequalities that can be satisfied simultaneously. On the following K lines print the found set of inequalities, one inequality per line, regardless of their order.

Sample input

X >= 3

X < 5

X < 6

X >= 3

X = 100

X < 3

X > 3

X <= -1

Sample output

5

X >= 3

X < 5

X < 6

X >= 3

X > 3

Explanation

These five inequalities are satisfied if X = 4. No greater subset has a solution.

Here is my code:

```
class Program
{
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
  Console.Write("Enter X: ");
  int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  List<string> result = ParseInequalities.Parse(x);

  Console.WriteLine("\nCount of inequalities is: {0}", result.Count);
  foreach (var item in result)
  {
   Console.WriteLine(item);
  }

 Console.ReadLine();
 }
}

public static class ParseInequalities
{
 public static List<string> Parse(int x)
 {
  List<string> inequalities = new List<string>();
  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"D:Sample.txt"))
  {
   string line = "";
   while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
    string[] parts = line.Split(' ');

    if (parts[1] == "=")
    {
      if (x == Convert.ToInt32(parts[2]))
      {
       inequalities.Add(line);
      }
    }
    else if (parts[1] == ">=")
    {
     if (x >= Convert.ToInt32(parts[2]))
     {
      inequalities.Add(line);
     }
    }
    else if (parts[1] == ">")
    {
     if (x > Convert.ToInt32(parts[2]))
     {
      inequalities.Add(line);
     }
    }
    else if (parts[1] == "<")
    {
     if (x < Convert.ToInt32(parts[2]))
     {
      inequalities.Add(line);
     }
    }
    else if (parts[1] == "<=")
    {
     if (x <= Convert.ToInt32(parts[2]))
     {
      inequalities.Add(line);
     }
    }

  }
  return inequalities;
  }
 }

}
```

This is a solution, but apparently not the one that should be provided.
May be I must look from a different angle, but I'm lacking in ideas.

My english is not very good, but I hope you understand me,

Thanks

Comment: Is there an upper bound to the max value of |X|?   Could you list all possible values and eliminate them from a list as you introduce each inequality that must be satisfied?  Kind of like Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: Everything that I've got is in the question, so I don't have answers to your questions :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are describing is finding a cardinality-maximal [clique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)) in an [interval graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_graph). More precisely, every line of the input is describing an interval on the real line. Without loss of generality, the half-closed intervals can be regarded as closed intervals; by processing the input, the largest and smallest boundaries (say `min` and `max`) can be searched and each half-closed interval can be closed by the respective value as follows.

```
X > C => max + 1 > X > C
X < C => min - 1 < X < C
```

These intervals constitute the node set of a graph; two nodes are connected by an edge if and only if they intersect. The problem is to find a clique as large as possible in this graph, and a desired value `X` can be found in the intersection of the intervals associated with the nodes of the graph.

According to [this publication](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/net.3230120410/abstract), there is an algorithm with runtime bound `O(n log n)` to determine a cardinality-maximal clique, although finding a clique in general graphs is [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#NP-completeness).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I didn't expect the solution to be so complex (Complex at least for me) :)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a sorted list of all occuring numbers: -1, 3, 5, 6, 100

Then select an arbitrary X in each interval: -1.5, 2, 4, 5.5, 50, 150

For all numbers from both list, check which one satisfies the most inequalities.

Runtime is O(n^2) rather than O(n logn), but for 50 inequalities this is probably good enough (and much simpler).

Comment: Could you be more specific on the selection of the 'arbitrary X in each interval'? How should it be chosen?

Comment: @Codor That doesn't matter. You could simply choose the center for the bounded intervals.

Comment: I don't think so. Consider the intervals `[1,3]`, `[3,5]`, `[5,7]`; your suggestion would check the values `2`, `4` and `6`, which are contained in exactly one interval each. The values `3` and `5` would be contained in two intervals each, however.

Comment: @Codor Yes, that's why you need to check the interval bounds as well. I edited my answer while you were writing the first comment.

Comment: @Henrik, thank you very much. I rewrote my code and I think that now my solution is correct.